# What is the difference between the residue classes / rings of the following polynomial rings mod ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am struggling with fully understanding the difference in structure and elements of the following rings:

1) $R[x]/(x+1)$
2) $R[x]/(x+2)$
3) $R[x]/(ax+1)$

I know when we mod by an ideal, the residue classes will have a degree less than the generator of the ideal.

So for example, when we mod R[x] by (x+1), we get residues of degree 0. That is, constant elements. But dividing by (x+2) yields the same degree, and thus the same elements.

Also for #3, how do we deal with non-monic polynomials?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify what's $R$ here?

Comment: Any arbitrary ring. Can you tell me how there is no difference? So if we mod by an ideal of a polynomial, the constant term does not affect anything?

Comment: Okay. If i remember correctly. Consider Z[x], and Z[x]/(x-1) is isomorphic to Z, but Z[x]/(x-2) is isomorphic to Z/2Z. Is that correct? If so, It contradicts the isomorphism statement above.

Comment: No, it is not isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. The latter has characteristic $2$, while the former is $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Pacemaker Yes, it is true that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2) \not\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In fact they are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. The isomorphism is given  by Bernard's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are not different: there's an isomorphism from each of them to R given by $\; \bar p\mapsto p\bmod (x+1) =p(-1)$ (resp. $\; \bar p\mapsto p\bmod (x+2) =p(-2)$).

The third one is different, if $a$ is not a unit, since there is no *Euclidean division* in $R(x)$, except by monic polynomials (or at least with leading coefficient a unit). $R[x]/(ax+1)$ is isomorphic to the *ring of fractions* of $R\;$ w.r.t. the multiplicative set $\{1, a, a^2,\dots, a^n,\dots\}$.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, Just one question regarding the first two.If I remember correctly. Consider Z[x], and Z[x]/(x-1) is isomorphic to Z, but Z[x]/(x-2) is isomorphic to Z/2Z. Is that correct? If so, It contradicts the isomorphism statement above.

Also, can you please clarify your notation of p bar, and p (-1)

Comment: The isomorphism is false, as I said in a comment above. The notation $\bar p$ is forthe class of $p$ in the quotient ring, and $p(-1)$ is, well…, the value of $p$ at $x=-1$. The remainder of the division of $p(x)$ by $x+1$ is but $p(-1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will think about it.